# The name of the letter, which is related to two English letters "gh"

Tags: orthography

What is the name of the marked letter, which in my opinion relates to the two modern English letters "gh"?

[image]

Comment: I have no rights to create the new tags. Which tag do you prefer?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogh